# How to generate static lib that contains all its dependencies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, linker, static-libraries

I am working on a project where we need to separate our application's mathematical routines to an independent SDK, that will be consumed by another application.

To avoid the overhead of building export definitions, we thought of creating a static lib. The issue here is that these mathematical routines are dependent on other libs so the client will have to include them too.

My question is: How can we create a static lib that contains all its dependencies within itself? Assume that I am trying to create a static lib C1.lib that depends on D1.lib, D2.lib and D3.lib. Now any client application that needs to use C1.lib will also have to list D1,D2 and D3 as its dependencies.

It is even possible to do that in Windows? Any explanation on how it can be done or why it can't be done will really be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `Librarian > General` you can add d1.lib, d2.lib and d3.lib under `Additional Dependencies`. These will be merged into your output lib.

Answer (score 1):

> It is even possible to do that in Windows

Yes: look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) for `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` -- it does *exactly* what you want.